# difference between conditions in join clause and where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to know the difference (visually) would be the best between the two following SELECT statements.

```
SELECT P.* and X.* 
FROM Table1 P
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table2 X ON
    and  p.B=x.B
and  p.C=x.C
and  p.F=x.F
and  p.D=x.D 

WHERE X.F= 1 and X.E=4
```

and

```
SELECT P.* and X.* 
FROM Table1 P
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE X.F= 1 and X.E =4) X
    and  p.B=x.B
and  p.C=x.C
and  p.F=x.F
and  p.D=x.D
```

They do not return the same number of rows. Lets say Table1 has 5000 rows and Table2 has 5000 rows also. The first `select join` statement returns ~40000 rows (specific to my query at work) and then when the `where` clause is applied, it returns about 2000 rows.

The second `select join` statement returns 5000 rows (original number). This is the number I want.

But I can't seem to understand why this is happening. My knowledge and visuallizing joins is a bit weak.

Sample Data: Please change the name of the temp tables, they are the same. Also I couldn't provide proper column names but have edited my code to indicate which columsn I want match
Here is TABLE1:

```
    SELECT * INTO #tmp_GridResults_1
FROM (
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] ) t;
SELECT [ID], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F]
FROM #tmp_GridResults_1

DROP TABLE #tmp_GridResults_1
GO
```

Here is Table2:
---------------   #tmp_GridResults_1   ---------------

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp_GridResults_1
FROM (
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'0' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'0' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'0' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'0' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'0' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'0' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'0' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'0' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'1' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'2' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'3' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'4' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'-1' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'0' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'1' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'1' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0' AS [ID], N'P' AS [B], N'2' AS [C], N'1' AS [D], N'98' AS [E], N'2' AS [F] ) t;
SELECT [ID], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F]
FROM #tmp_GridResults_1

DROP TABLE #tmp_GridResults_1
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put filter criteria in the WHERE clause, and that criteria dictates conditions against the "outer" tables of a join, you effectively turn that outer join into an inner join. Filter criteria against an outer join table belongs in the join, not in the where.

How many rows does this version yield?

```
SELECT P.*, X.* 
FROM Table1 P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 X
    on P.Id = X.id 
    and P.name = X.name 
    and P.age = X.age 
    AND X.bar = 1 
    and X.name ='value';
```

Theoretically, this should yield >= the number of rows in your first statement, and = the number of rows in your second.

If you want to compare this with your existing result, you can do:

```
SELECT P.*, X.* 
FROM Table1 P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 X
    on P.Id = X.id 
    and P.name = X.name 
    and P.age = X.age 
    AND X.bar = 1 
    and X.name ='value'
EXCEPT
SELECT P.* and X.*
FROM Table1 P
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE X.bar = 1 and X.name ='value') X
    on P.Id = X.id 
    and P.name = X.name 
    and P.age = X.age;
```

If you get no results, they're the same. You could also do it the opposite way:

```
SELECT P.*, X.* 
FROM Table1 P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 X
    on P.Id = X.id 
    and P.name = X.name 
    and P.age = X.age 
    AND X.bar = 1 
    and X.name ='value'
INTERSECT
SELECT P.* and X.*
FROM Table1 P
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE X.bar = 1 and X.name ='value') X
    on P.Id = X.id 
    and P.name = X.name 
    and P.age = X.age;
```

If you get 5000 rows (or whatever the exact row count is for the latter query by itself), then the result sets are the same.

Comment: True, but the OP mentions that even without the where clause he gets ~4000 rows rather than the full 5000.

Comment: I get about 4000 rows from the first select statement. When I put the condition in the join then it works fine.

Comment: @masfenix can you provided a much smaller set of sample data that demonstrates the problem? And by `TableB` do you mean `Table2`? If so then yes. You want all the rows in table 1, and any rows that match in table 2 (otherwise NULL).

Comment: @SachinKainth I don't see how it conflicts with my explanation. The 40000 (not 4000) rows he talks about are *without* the where clause. Please read closely.

Comment: Your edit returns the SAME number of rows as the second select statement where it returns the correct number. I just need to compare the data now to see if it is the same data. Any quick way to compare two tables? I will try posting sample data.

Comment: @masfenix added a couple of examples to the answer.

Comment: I have added sample data as insert statements so its easier for you to run this. But I think at this point we have figured it out and I kinda understand the problem. I couldn't attach column names because of work issues but I have updated my code to match the columns